# How to compare dates in an Activiti Task in Alfresco using javascript?

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

I'm developing a custom advanced Activiti workflow for Alfresco.

In a form, there's a date field where the user has to enter a date greater than today's. So I have to compare the dates. I created a Service Task to handle that, as shown below:

```
<serviceTask id="serviceTask2" name="Disposal Postpone" activiti:class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.script.AlfrescoScriptDelegate">
        <extensionElements>
            <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:expression>
                    var today = new Date();

                    if (workflowdocumentdisposal_datefield != undefined){
                        if( workflowdocumentdisposal_datefield > today ){
                            //Do the job
                        }
                    }
                </activiti:expression>
            </activiti:field>
        </extensionElements>
    </serviceTask>
```

The problem is that the value of datefield comes in a odd format

> Fri Oct 17 00:00:00 BRT 2014

I've tried to use some javascript functions, like Date.parse(), and Alfresco's utils.fromISO8601(). But none of them worked, throwing errors.

How can I check if the datefield's value, with this format, is greater than today using javascript?

Comment: Using split method,split your date.After that join 0,1,2 element of your date array and than parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I would  have checked the date upfront with client side JavaScript.

Just create a form controller with a date and when populating add an extra validation to it.

In YUI you can supply a minimum date, take a look here: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/calendar/